# What happens when an aws emr core node dies in a hadoop environment

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster with 1 master and 2 core nodes. This automatically set the replication factor to 1. So what I read from the documentation this means that when a file is uploaded on a node then it's stored only on that node. In my case I have a spark application which was running pretty good until one of the core nodes died for some reason which I still investigate. When that node died my application died as well with the following error:

> Diagnostics: Could not obtain block: BP-1346795555-172.31.18.53-1503395276403:blk_1073762933_22444 file=/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1503580640490_3075/__spark_libs__1454218958107463026.zip

So I interpret this in the following way: Spark libs were located on the node which died and as the replication factor is 1 they were not stored elsewhere. This lead to a file corruption. Am I correct in my reasoning or there's another explanation of what happened? And if I'm correct what is the best way to avoid that situation? The easiest to think is to have more core nodes and to increase the replication factor which will lead to having the data on more nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Spark's staging directory is not located on a distributed file system and is not replicated at all. This is just a local storage for the machine. If executor is lost it is lost as well, but in a well designed application it should not result in a permanent data loss.

Comment: Ok, but as I can see the error it tries to obtain a hadoop block which is most probably missing because of the dead node. And what do you mean by well designed application? I think my problems come from not well configured hadoop environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly right.

If a node died, then all you can do is add more than 3 nodes, so the replication factor will be 2 *or* manually set the *dfs.replication* to 2, so even if you have 2 nodes your data will be replicated 2 times.

Be also aware that such errors may occur due to running out of memory and that's why the blocks become unavailable. When Linux runs out of memory it runs something called the OOM Killer and that sometimes kills important processes. To prevent this from happening you can:

1. run on instances with more memory
2. adjust the cluster configuration to run fewer tasks per node
3. modify your application to use memory more efficiently and avoid shuffle

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't think that the memory is the problem as I have separate configurations for the yarn cluster memory and os memory and I think it's pretty much enough. Actually at the moment my application is running without doing much work as I'm only testing it. So it almost doesn't perform any tasks.

Comment: So, why don't you set set the dfs.replication to 2 to avoid any future problems?

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm going to do. Thanks.